# how make that a div is contained in other divs and doesn't overflow

Tags: overflow, media-queries, css

I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/cN2pS/embedded/result/
And I'm looking for the best way to adapt the divs inside the circles (text and number) in order to these divs (text and number) don't overflow of the circles......I don't know if I'm explaining well, but in different resolutions, sometimes, text overflow of circles.....
When you visit the link above of jsfiddle, try to resize the window and you'll can see the left-bottom circle, that contains *Zona de Información*, its text overflow...
Regards, Daniel

**EDIT**: It looks like works better by adding **overflow:hidden;** and reducing the font-size to 14px. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/cN2pS/8/embedded/result/

**EDIT2**: Only one question more: do you know any tutorial, live examples, etc, with efficient use of media queries in order to adapt to resolutions of mobile devices? in order to adapt these circulars divs...Or I have to resize my desktop browser window much times...Any *magic* tool for this? :) Thanks

Thanks very much for help.

Comment: You do not want to use `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Yes, I used it, look at this edited jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cN2pS/4/embedded/result/ I use overflow:hidden and it continues equal

Comment: Can you edit your fiddle to show your problem?

Comment: I edited adding overflow:hidden jsfiddle.net/cN2pS/4/embedded/result

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use CSS **word-wrap: break-word;** property for this:

```
#divInfIzq {
    bottom: 15%;
    left: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cN2pS/5/embedded/result/

Comment: Yes, I added word-wrap: break-word; and I'm seeing in jsfiddle, it's like your...but the letter n positionates alone at the end of the circle...

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for something like this?

http://www.we-are-gurus.com/tools/responsive-design-tester.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsmore.rvadv.com&d=320x480&scroll=off

I use this when I am designing for mobile devices and it works pretty well.